# get CommandArgument from ImageButton onClick, VB

Tags: asp.net, onclick, commandargument

I have a series of ImageButtons...when I click on the image, I want to redirect to another page, using the CommandArgument as a uniqueId...How can i get the commandArgument from the onclick event? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use the OnClick event. Use the OnCommand event

```
Protected Sub ImageButton1_Command(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)
    Dim arg As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()

    ' use arg
End Sub
```