# Passing parameters in an ASP.Net DetailsView image button OnClick event handler

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, onclick, parameter-passing, detailsview

Is it possible to send a parameter in an ASP.Net image button OnClick event handler to a code-behind file?

In a DetailsView we have this markup for each day of the week for the Edit template and on top of that another bunch of coding for the insert template:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
    <asp:ImageButton 
        ID="ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekMonday" 
        runat="server" 
        ImageUrl='<%# getCheckboxImageToDisplay(Eval("DayOfWeekMonday"))%>' 
        Height="15"
        Width="15" 
        OnClick="ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekMonday_Click"
        CausesValidation="False">
    </asp:ImageButton>
</EditItemTemplate>
```

The handler in the code-behind file:

```
Protected Sub ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekTuesday_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs)

    Dim imgTheImageButton As New ImageButton

    imgTheImageButton = DetailsView.FindControl("ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekTuesday")

    If imgTheImageButton.ImageUrl = "../../Images/checked.png" = True Then

        imgTheImageButton.ImageUrl = "../../Images/unchecked.png"
        LabelCheckBoxTuesday.Text = False
    Else

        imgTheImageButton.ImageUrl = "../../Images/checked.png"
        LabelCheckBoxTuesday.Text = True
    End If
End Sub
```

That will amount to a lot of coding.

Is it possible to do create a single handler and call it like this?

```
OnClick="ImageButtonDayOfWeek_Click("Monday", "Edit")
```

The only difference between all the handlers is:

```
imgTheImageButton = DetailsView.FindControl("ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekTuesday")
```

It would be nice to just use a bunch of if statements inside a single handler and use the appropriate "ID" to place in DetailsView.FindControl.

Answer (score 0):

In your ImageButton, add a CommandArgument property:

```
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:ImageButton 
    ID="ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekMonday" 
    runat="server" 
    ImageUrl='<%# getCheckboxImageToDisplay(Eval("DayOfWeekMonday"))%>' 
    Height="15"
    Width="15" 
    OnClick="ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekMonday_Click"
    CommandArgument='<%# Eval("DayOfWeekMonday") %>'
    CausesValidation="False">
</asp:ImageButton>
```

Then in your code-behind:

```
Protected Sub ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekTuesday_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)

    //e.CommandArgument should contain the actual value of DayOfWeekMonday
    Dim arg As String = e.CommandArgument.ToString()

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I used: CommandArgument="Monday, Edit" but when I type e. in the code behind file, I only get e.x and e.y as the possible values and not e.CommandArgument. Did I leave something out?

Comment: I changed the parameters of `ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekTuesday_Click` in the code behind. Try it. I got that from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7957816/get-commandargument-from-imagebutton-onclick-vb

Comment: Hi I get this error when I changed it to (ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs): Compiler Error Message: BC31143: Method 'Protected Sub ImageButtonEditDayOfWeekMonday_Click(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.CommandEventArgs)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub ImageClickEventHandler(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.ImageClickEventArgs)'.

Comment: The error message is real cryptic. Looks like it's possible it can't be done with image buttons.